# Does vcl.load include related files?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

In [Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/), we can load a particular configuration file and tell Varnish to use it.

For example, a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate a unique timestamp ID for this version of the VCL
TIME=$(date +%s)

# Load the file into memory
varnishadm vcl.load varnish_$TIME /etc/varnish/default.vcl

# Active this Varnish config
varnishadm vcl.use varnish_$TIME
```

Run with:

```
$ ./varnishconf 
VCL compiled.

VCL 'varnish_1604136350' now active
```

However, if `default.vcl` includes other vcl files, it's not clear if `vcl.use` will also use that version of those included files?

For example, in `default.vcl`:

```
include "includes/backend.vcl";
```

is `backends.vcl` state included in that `vcl.use` version?

Does varnish include the dependent included files from `vcl.load` in `vcl.use` ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Varnish processes the full VCL file when `vcl.load` is executed.

`varnishadm vcl.load` triggers the *VCC*, which is the compiler. The same *VCC* is triggered when `varnishd` is started, so there's not really a difference here.

In regards to include files: when the *VCC* thread is started, every `include` statement is parsed and the content it refers to is pasted inline. Once all includes have been parsed, *Varnish* can start tokenizing, and compiling the full VCL.